# how to use aync and await inside use effect of calling function?

Tags: reactjs

I am calling following functions like below.
How I can give async await to the serviceRequest and success handler

```js
useEffect(() => {
    serviceRequest(
      "URL",
      success,
      error
    );
  }, []);
  
   const success = (response) => { }
   const error = (error) => { }
```

```js
export const serviceRequest = (endpoint,successCallBack,errorCallBack) => {
    const options: any = {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      }
    axios.get(endpoint, options)
        .then((response) => {
            successCallBack(response.data)
        }) 
        .catch(error => {errorCallBack(error) })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first make sure that the serviceRequest function returns a promise. In this case you could simply return the axios result:

```
export const serviceRequest = (endpoint,successCallBack,errorCallBack) => {
const options: any = {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }

  return axios.get(endpoint, options)
}
```

Then you can use the promise in your use-effect handler, catching the result / error in a useState hook like this:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  serviceRequest("URL")
    .then((result) => setState(result)
    .catch(error => setState(error)
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decalre an async function in the `useEffect` and call it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const callApi = async () => {
    await serviceRequest("URL", success, error);
  };

  callApi();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await serviceRequest("URL", success, error);
    })()
}, []);
```